# Why do these increments give different results?

Tags: c++, increment

The operator `++` should be equivalent to `+ 1`, so why does the following example produce different results?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int i, n=25;
    std::string s1="a", s2="a", s1p="", s2p="";

    for (i=0;i<=n;i++)
    {
        s1p += s1;
        s1 = s1.at(0) + 1;

        s2p += s2;
        s2 = s2.at(0)++;
    }
    std::cout << "s1p = " << s1p << "\n" << "s2p = " << s2p << "\n";

    return 0;
}

Ouput:
s1p = abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
s2p = aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Comment: I seem to have this tendency lately to ask really ill-considered questions - maybe I've a subliminal wish to equal the "goesto-operator" question., although that will take some doing :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post-increment returns the value previously held by the variable.

Think of `x++` (**post-increment**) as

```
int y = x;
x = x+1;
return y;
```

and of `++x` (**pre-increment**) as

```
x = x+1;
return x;
```

To achieve your desired result, you need pre-increment.

Comment: Aaah yes, amazing how something obvious goes slipping by  ... LOL

Comment: Given that he's overwriting the results of the incrementation with an assignment anyway, I would question either the assignment, or the use of the increment operator (post or pre).  One or the other (depending on what he wants), but not both.

Answer (score 4):

The statement:

```
s2 = s2.at(0) ++;
```

is curious, to say the least.  You're modifying `s2` twice in the same
statement.  On a build-in type, this would be undefined behavior; on a
user defined type (like `std::string`), it's just confusing.  And because
the side effects of the ++ must occur before the call to `operator=`,
the `++` is effectively a no-op; any modification of any character in
`s2` is overwritten by the assignment.

If your goal is to assign a totally new value to the string, based on
its first character (and ignoring any additional characters it might
contain), then your modification of `s1` is the correct solution.  If
your goal is to modify the first character in the string, leaving any
other characters unchanged, then the correct solution is simply
`s.at(0) ++`, `++ s.at(0)` or `s.at(0) += 1`, without any assignment.
(The second is the most idiomatic, when the results are not otherwise
used.)  And of course, if you want to build up a string of successive
characters of the alphabet:

```
std::string s;
for ( char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ++ ch ) {
    s += ch;
}
```

would be the most idiomatic (even though it's formally wrong, and won't
work in some environments: there's no guarantee that the letters of the
alphabet occupy consecutive codepoints in the encoding).

Comment: You are right. I am testing a string hash-function and wanted to run through strings from "a" through "ab", "abc", ..., "a..z" to check for collisions. My initial attempt was s2 which obviously did not work, and I then switched to s1 which is fine. I got so involved with the hash-function that I failed to spot the simple wrong interpretation of post-increment - which resulted in this slightly embarrassing question.

Answer (score 2):

++ and +1 are not equivalent. To substitute `n++;` you have to use `n = n+1;` (or `n+=1` if you want). ++ actually increments a variable whereas +1 just returns the result of the arithmetic operation. also note that n++ and ++n have different behavior.

```
n = 1;
i = 1;

a = ++n;
b = i++;
c = i;
```

The output for a, b and c would be

```
a: 2
b: 1
c: 2
```